export datatable con filtros de fecha
Hola este es mi codigo js para mis tablas pero al momento de exportar en excel o copiar me copia toda la tabla en la tabla abajo tengo unos buscadores de columnas si filtro por ese metodo si puedo exportar solo eso ayudenme
ejemplo filtro en la fecha el dia 1 al dia 5 y me trae toda la base pero si filtro un dato en los buscadores de abajo si me copia o me exporta lo filtrado
$(document).ready(function() {
// Inicializar DataTable
var table = $('#tablawap').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'excel', 'pdf'
    ]
});

// Agregar filtros de búsqueda por columna
$('#tablawap tfoot th').each(function() {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Buscar ' + title + '" />');
});

// Aplicar filtros de búsqueda por columna
table.columns().every(function() {
    var that = this;

    $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function() {
        if (that.search() !== this.value) {
            that
                .search(this.value)
                .draw();
        }
    });
});

// Evento para filtrar por fecha mínima y máxima
$('#min, #max').on('change', function() {
    // Filtrar las fechas dentro del rango especificado
    var minDate = $('#min').val();
    var maxDate = $('#max').val();

    // Filtrar las fechas dentro del rango especificado
    if (minDate !== '' && maxDate !== '') {
        // Convertir las fechas a objetos Date para facilitar la comparación
        var minDateObj = new Date(minDate);
        var maxDateObj = new Date(maxDate);

        // Iterar sobre todas las filas de la tabla
        table.rows().every(function() {
            var rowData = this.data();
            var dateInRow = new Date(rowData[4]); // Suponiendo que la fecha está en la quinta columna

            // Mostrar u ocultar la fila según si la fecha está dentro del rango especificado
            if (dateInRow >= minDateObj && dateInRow <= maxDateObj) {
                this.nodes().to$().show(); // Mostrar la fila
            } else {
                this.nodes().to$().hide(); // Ocultar la fila
            }
        });
    } else {
        // Si no se especifica un rango, mostrar todas las filas
        table.rows().nodes().to$().show();
    }

    // Volver a habilitar los botones de exportación
    table.buttons().enable();
});

});
